# Tor doesn't connect to censored ISP - Stuck on Establishing an encrypted directory connection

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, help

I am on a connection where I have to sign in, when a browser starts.

Here is the log, how should I make it work?:

```
06/10/2015 15:36:32.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/10/2015 15:36:32.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/10/2015 15:36:32.500 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/10/2015 15:36:32.500 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/10/2015 15:36:32.500 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\YALTO\Tor Browser Experimental\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
06/10/2015 15:36:38.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
06/10/2015 15:36:38.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
06/10/2015 15:36:59.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:47779 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
06/10/2015 15:36:59.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 169.229.59.75:46328 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
06/10/2015 15:36:59.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:80 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
06/10/2015 15:36:59.700 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 109.105.109.163:38980 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
06/10/2015 15:39:05.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
06/10/2015 15:39:05.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
06/10/2015 15:39:05.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```